# Disable PIN caching for Virtual Smart Cards

Tags: certificate, smartcard, pin, pki

We want to store digital certificates for PDF signing on **Virtual** Smart Cards. The default behavior for PIN entering is that the PIN is only entered once during a session. Is it possible to change this to "always prompt", so that the PIN has to be entered each time a digital certificate from the VSC is used for signing a document?

Thanks!

Comment: You need to set up strong private key protection. This might be an option when importing the certificates, or when the certificates were created.

Answer (score 0):

You need to ask the Virtual smart card vendor the question. With real smart cards, the PIN is used to unlock the card so the card can use the private key stored on the card to do a sign operation on the card. Many cards only require the PIN be entered once, and the card stays unlocked until it is powered down or the middle ware or application does something else to cause the card to become locked. But some cards can enforce a "PIN Always", "User Consent" (PKCS#15) or "CKA_ALWAYS_AUTHENTICATE" (PKCS#11) restriction on the card to limit the number of sign operations that can be done with one entry of the PIN. The middle ware or calling application may also be caching the PIN to get around the card restriction.